# asks the user for an angle in degrees between 0 and 180

Tags: java

My program accepts any number that I input even 1 million >.<
but I only wanted to ask the user to input an angle in degrees between 0 to 180 and outputs
the sine, cosine and tangent of that angle

here is my program :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class Mathematics
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {

    System.out.println("Enter an Angle ");
    Scanner data = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x;
    x=data.nextInt();

    double sinx = Math.sin( Math.toRadians(x) );
    double cosx = Math.cos( Math.toRadians(x) );
    double tanx = Math.tan( Math.toRadians(x) );

    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
    System.out.println("Sine of a circle is  " + format.format(sinx));
    System.out.println("cosine of a circle is  " + format.format(cosx));
    System.out.println("tangent of a circle is  " + format.format(tanx));

  }
}
```

Comment: It might be, but [that's okay](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Very likely so, but the OP has made a decent effort to answer the question and is seeking assistance on a single issue...

Comment: yes this is a homework question and the question is like this

"Exercise 4. Trigonometry.java
Write a program that asks the user for an angle in degrees between 0 and 180 and outputs
the sine, cosine and tangent of that angle, rounded to 2 decimal places."


and yeah Im a student and new to programming....

Answer (score 3):

Put this code after `x=data.nextInt();`

```
if( x < 0 || x > 180 )
{
    throw new Exception("You have entered an invalid value");
}
```

This will cause your program to crash if the user inputs a number outside the range [0, 180].
If you wish to allow the user to try again, you would need to put the program into a loop, like so:

```
do
{
    System.out.print("Enter a value in [0, 180]: ");
    x = data.nextInt();
} while(x < 0 || x > 180);
```

This loop will continue until the user enters the desired values.

Comment: I think `throw new IllegalArgumentException(..` would be more appropriate for this case.

Comment: Perhaps, but then again the value x is not an argument to anything, it is user input...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
x = data.nextInt();
```

write

```
do {
    x = data.nextInt();
    if (x < 0 || x > 180) {
        System.out.println("Please enter number between 0-180");
    }
} while (x < 0 || x > 180);
```

Comment: Not to be picky, but this code is unnecessarily complex (the if statement is redundant)

Comment: -sir Sameh Kamal
my reputation awhile ago was 12 and now its 18,, now I can accept answers ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Put the question in a loop. When the user enters a value that is outside your range, print an error message and request a different value. When the entered value is OK, *then* you can exit the loop. It is better to use a function to make things more readable:

```
public static int askForInt(String question, String error, int min, int max) {
    while (true) {
       System.out.print(question + " (an integer between " + min + " and " + max + "): ");
       int read = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
       if (read >= min && read <= max) {
          return read;
       } else {
          System.out.println(error + " " + in + " is not a valid input. Try again.");
       }
    }
}
```

Call like this: `x = askForInt("The angle", "Invalid angle", 0, 180);`